# Can I extend a model without extending its table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a model class that looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere else in my code I have added a **private** subclass:

```
private class Bar : Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I scaffold a migration, I get this:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Foo", "Name", c => c.String());
AddColumn("dbo.Foo", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
```

I didn't think Entity Framework would find out there is a `Bar` subclass, since it's privately nested within a controller, outside of the `Models` namespace. Can I stop EF from modifying the  table?

I tried `[NotMapped]` to ignore the `Name` property, but EF still adds a `Discriminator` column because of the inheritance strategy it uses.

Comment: Did you try adding that attribute over your `Bar` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `[NotMapped]` attribute on your whole class.

This is the definition of this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class NotMappedAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

`AttributeUsage` say you can use it on class and not just on property.